# How to realise generic abstract class?

Tags: typescript, abstract-class, typescript2.0

I have abstract class:

```
abstract class AScore<T> {
  constructor(
    protected data: T) {}
}
```

I implement this class like:

```
class GetActivitiesPupil implements AScore<number> {}
```

Compiler says it is wrong implementation of class

Comment: `class GetActivitiesPupil extends AScore<number> {}`?

Comment: Sure, it extends

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to extend the abstract class to create a concrete instance i.e.

```
abstract class AScore<T> {
  constructor(protected data: T) {}
}

class GetActivitiesPupil extends AScore<number> {
  data: number;

  constructor(data: number) {
   super(data)}
  }
}

const test = new GetActivitiesPupil(123);
console.log(test.data) // Outputs 123
```

You can see that this code has no errors [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=abstract%20class%20AScore%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20protected%20data%3A%20T)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20GetActivitiesPupil%20extends%20AScore%3Cnumber%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20data%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20constructor(data%3A%20number)%20%7Bsuper(data)%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20test%20%3D%20new%20GetActivitiesPupil(123)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(test.data)%20%2F%2F%20Outputs%20123).

Comment: Why you added this: `data: number;`?

Comment: Why I ca not pass T in `GetActivitiesPupil`?

Comment: You are passing T in GetActivitiesPupil; in this case T is number. I'm including "data: number" as a concrete instance would store the data defined in the abstract base class. This code would work without "data: number" but in practice it would a useless class.